# DateTime default value ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, asp.net-core

For a student project, I want to add default value - in the date field(ReleaseDate) but still have a calendar and the option of choosing a date.

[image: Here is a screenshot of what it looks like]

My code in Models/Post.cs:

```
[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode =true, DataFormatString = "{0: yyyy-MM-dd}")]

public System.DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

And in View/Posts/Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I try timur but
Controllers/PostController.cs

Is see only one define of index:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
        }
```

And your code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Post()
    {
        ReleaseDate = DateTime.Today
    };

    return View("View", model);
}
```

[I try to put like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEqLq.png)
[But there is an error (on https://localhost:numbers/Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhmi2.png)

Views/Posts/Create.cshtml

```
@model Portal.Models.Post

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create -";
}


<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Post</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

And Views/Posts/Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Portal.Models.Post>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Job Rice -";
}

<!-- Image -->
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="full-width-image">
            <img src="img/background.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>





<div class="text-center">
<h1><a asp-action="Create">Create new offer</a></h1>
    </div>


        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="my-5"> </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 sm-12">
                <!-- Card -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-center colores">
                        <h4> <i class="fas fa-poll-h"></i> <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) </a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card content -->
                    <form class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="text-center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</div>
                                <div class="float-right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> 
                                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
}
```

Comment: will setting [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) upfront help?

Comment: Where exactly? Can you put example?

Comment: You probably need to add value. Eg. acts as placeholder

Answer (score 12):

As Tieson T. points in his comment, you have to add the "value" attribute to the "input" tag in your razor page:

```
<input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
```

Of course, you can replace "DateTime.Today" with something else.

It doesn't matter that your browser shows the date in different format, you have to use this one inside the value attribute. I just tested it in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor app and it works.

Comment: I was missing the date format inside the ToString() method. I makes sense since that is what my Data Annotation is asking for

Answer (score 3):

This should instantiate a default value:

```
public System.DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; } = System.DateTime.Today;
```

alternatively if you need time as well

```
public System.DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; } = System.DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following Razor syntax for this purpose.

```
<input type="date" asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" value=@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") />
```

You just have to put ***type=date***.

Answer (score 1):

Since Razor views still allow you write html, you could try to define yours as

```cs
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" value="@Model.ReleaseDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

it should render the current model value as starting point for your input, of course you need to define one before passing it down onto a view:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Post()
    {
        ReleaseDate = DateTime.Today
    };

    return View("View", model);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't really need to do `<input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" value="@Model.ReleaseDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />`; `<input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />` is enough, given the data annotations on the model (aside from the extra space which shouldn't be in the format).

Comment: I had a bit of an issue when trying that. I think the date formatting locale might be at play. I'd invite OP to try both methods and see what works

Comment: The tag helper should be generating a `<input type="date" />` tag. Assuming it is, the only valid format _is_ `yyyy-MM-dd` (an ISO-8601 short date) - anything else won't be parsed correctly by the native date inputs.